# Select array object that contains object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, something like this example:

```
var b = [
  {
    'attribute[170]': "41", 
    'attribute[171]': "15",
    'data': 1,
    'something': 'some text'
  },
  {
    'attribute[150]': "401", 
    'attribute[181]': "5",
    'test': '1234',
    'data': 2.3
  }
];
```

I want to select the object out of the array in `b` that contains the attributes of object `a`

```
var a = {
  'attribute[170]': "41", 
  'attribute[171]': "15"
};
```

Is this possible, maybe with `jQuery.grep` or mapping? (I am using jQuery.)

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. It *does* have to do with JavaScript. I've retagged and updated for you.

Comment: You only want to match if **all** of `a`'s properties match the entry from `b`, right? So there'd be no match if `a`'s `attribute[171]` were `"42"` instead of `"15"` given the `b` shown...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `filter` to loop through `b`, and loop through `a`'s properties looking for matches on each entry in `b`. It can be useful to grab a list of `a`'s properties in advance.

```
var aprops = Object.keys(a);
var c = b.filter(function(entry) {
  return aprops.every(function(key) {
    return entry[key] === a[key];
  });
});
```

```js
var b = [
  {
    'attribute[170]': "41", 
    'attribute[171]': "15",
    'data': 1,
    'something': 'some text'
  },
  {
    'attribute[150]': "401", 
    'attribute[181]': "5",
    'test': '1234',
    'data': 2.3
  }
];
var a = {
  'attribute[170]': "41", 
  'attribute[171]': "15"
};

var aprops = Object.keys(a);
var c = b.filter(function(entry) {
  return aprops.every(function(key) {
    return entry[key] === a[key];
  });
});
console.log(c);
```

Or using ES2015+ syntax:

```
const aprops = Object.keys(a);
const c = b.filter(entry => aprops.every(key => entry[key] === a[key]));
```

```js
const b = [
  {
    'attribute[170]': "41", 
    'attribute[171]': "15",
    'data': 1,
    'something': 'some text'
  },
  {
    'attribute[150]': "401", 
    'attribute[181]': "5",
    'test': '1234',
    'data': 2.3
  }
];
const a = {
  'attribute[170]': "41", 
  'attribute[171]': "15"
};

const aprops = Object.keys(a);
const c = b.filter(entry => aprops.every(key => entry[key] === a[key]));
console.log(c);
```

That gives you an array with *all* matching objects. If you only want the first matching object, not in an array, you'd use `find` (added in ES2015 aka ES6, but easily polyfilled/shimmed) instead of `filter`:

```
var aprops = Object.keys(a);
var c = b.find(function(entry) {
  return aprops.every(function(key) {
    return entry[key] === a[key];
  });
});
```

```js
var b = [
  {
    'attribute[170]': "41", 
    'attribute[171]': "15",
    'data': 1,
    'something': 'some text'
  },
  {
    'attribute[150]': "401", 
    'attribute[181]': "5",
    'test': '1234',
    'data': 2.3
  }
];
var a = {
  'attribute[170]': "41", 
  'attribute[171]': "15"
};

var aprops = Object.keys(a);
var c = b.find(function(entry) {
  return aprops.every(function(key) {
    return entry[key] === a[key];
  });
});
console.log(c);
```

Or using ES2015+ syntax:

```
const aprops = Object.keys(a);
const c = b.find(entry => aprops.every(key => entry[key] === a[key]));
```

```js
const b = [
  {
    'attribute[170]': "41", 
    'attribute[171]': "15",
    'data': 1,
    'something': 'some text'
  },
  {
    'attribute[150]': "401", 
    'attribute[181]': "5",
    'test': '1234',
    'data': 2.3
  }
];
const a = {
  'attribute[170]': "41", 
  'attribute[171]': "15"
};

const aprops = Object.keys(a);
const c = b.find(entry => aprops.every(key => entry[key] === a[key]));
console.log(c);
```